# Providing second *.config file to existing app

Tags: .net, configuration, batch-file, msbuild, version

I need to run program that has its default configuration (if it helps, it is .net framework's MSBuild.exe) and provide additional configuration (rebind 3rd party assembly versions).

The problem is that I don't want to alter existing MSBuild configuration. It would work for me, but each other person running my build script would have to do the same, which is undesired.
Can I do this some way automatically without altering existing MSBuild configuration ?

Current batch build content:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild BuildRelease.msbuild
```

Config, that I need to merge with existing one:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="xunit.extensions" publicKeyToken="8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.6.1.1521" newVersion="1.9.1.1600"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.1.416.3" newVersion="4.0.10827.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```